# How to compare a string with the name of a data field?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my application in Angular (with TypeScript language).
I need to compare a string data field, such as "string4" with the NAME of an object.
Example:

```
export class MyClass {
  string1: string;
  anyobject: Object;
  string2: string;
  // etc...
}
```

If I have a method such as:

```
myMethod(parameter: string) {

}
```

I want the value inside the parameter match as the name of a data field in my MyClass.
For example, is parameter  has value "string2", I want to get the string2 value of MyClass (that will be another string).

Comment: Can't you use switch case? Or may be loop through MyClass variables and get the index of that name.

Comment: I suggest you go back to your JS tutorial (TypeScript is just a typing layer on top of JavaScript) and review the basic information about objects and how to access their properties. You could start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors.

Answer (score 0):

You can access object properties without the dot notation. For example like this

`MyClassObject["value"]` and in your case it would be `MyClassObject[parameter]`

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aiaqz4?file=app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks! But I have another problem. MyClassObject[parameter] 
gives me the correct value, but I can't change the object!
If i tried:
MyClassObject[parameter] = "newString";
This instruction does not change the instance data field

Comment: @claudioz It does change it. Maybe you have the wrong instance. Because that statement is another form of the `.dot` notation. It works the same

Comment: Yes, I wont to assign a new value to the object identified by MyClassObject[parameter]

Comment: It finds the correct value (prints the right data field with console.log). But i can't change it with any assignments!

Comment: @claudioz You might want to include the code on how you are assigning values to your post or even better open a new question.

Comment: you just need to do `this.MyClassObject[parameter] = 'some new value';`